# How to configure DFP no to place an empty place holder if there is no ad?

Tags: banner, google-dfp

We have a 728X90 banner in our site. For some countries we don't have a banner to display and from some reason the DFP still holds the empty space.

How can we configure it to only occupy the space if a banner is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `collapseEmptyDivs` method.

You can read more about it here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3072674?hl=en